# can we auto scale stateless service based on connection count

Tags: azure, microservices, azure-service-fabric, autoscaling, service-fabric-stateless

We have stateless service deployed in service fabric need to auto scale.

Here is the requirement to create new service instance every time when connection count to the service reaches a threshold(per say 10000 requests/connections), need to spawn a service instance. Do we have any pre-defined metric we can use to auto scale the service like servicefabric:/_MemoryInMB, or is it going to be a custom metric, if it is custom metric then in stateless service how can I keep the count of number of connections/requests made to the service.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks, 
Ram

Comment: in my opinion you should not scale based on connection count, and the reason is because a request can terminate very quickly. So you'd rather monitor your VM's resources and scale based on them

Comment: Thiago, I think it is very common need to scale out if the number of requests in flow to a particular instance is too high, we spawn another instance to share the requests(like balancing load). I for e-commerce sites this is what happens in the cloud.